# Putting font awesome icons in toast controller in ionic 4

Tags: icons, font-awesome, ionic4, toast

Is there any way to put an icon beside the toast-message in Toast Controller in ionic 4?

I create the toast controller with the `toastController.create()` method and pass the `cssClass` property, is there any way to put an font awesome icon with this class passed in the `cssClass` property? Like exporting the `fal-fa-icon` class in the css?

I want to do something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. I tried to use ion icon cheet in css but the `toast-message` or `toast-container` class do not change with any style.

Comment: That is because toast use a shadow Dom.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to add a font-awesome icon but if you would be happy with an image you can add it directly into the message of the toast:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/icon-in-toast/113750/4

Or you can use an ion-icon, Example:

```
this.toastController.create({
    message: '<ion-icon name="bicycle"></ion-icon>   Cycling saves the world!',
    duration: 2000,
    color: 'success'
});
```

Comment: It is no longer possible to inject HTML into the message prop, and hasn't been for some time.

Comment: On Ionic version 5.6, it is possible to inject HTML into the toast message but there is some stripping taking place e.g. the style attribute is removed from tags.